# How do I import attributes with the feed mapper?

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a Drupal 7 instance with Ubercart 3, and I'm also using the [Ubercart Feed Mappers](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_feeds) module to map out the importing of product fields. I have all the fields, images and categories working well, but not attributes.

I've searched high and low for an answer or a short how to for importing attributes and multiple attributes for each product but with no success. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need 'UC Feeds Product Importer' a sub module built to import all the product related fields.

check this: https://drupal.org/node/1802908

1. Create an importer (at admin/structure/feeds/create). Or try my default importer module, which creates a csv importer from all Ubercart fields - including attributes - automatically. If you use it, please leave feedback on the issue!
2. Download the template from the import page (if you use the default importer above, it will be at /import/uc_feeds_product_importer/template)
3. Fill in the template. For each attribute option you want enabled, fill in at least one of the cells for weight, price, or cost (a zero value works). If you fill in at least one of the three, any unfilled will default to zero. If you leave all three blank, that option will not be enabled on the imported product.
4. Import the completed csv at /import/uc_feeds_product_importer (if you're using my module above), otherwise go to /import and choose the importer you created.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubercart.org/project/node_import_uc_stock#comment-55048
Node Import and Ubercart File Download Integration

I've extended node_import_supported_v5.zip to add support for importing "Ubercart File Downloads". The only modification between my version and v5 is that I've added this patch to resolve an issue with node_import and PHP 5.3

I've also included the additional doxygen generated API docs, so that hopefully others will be able to get a handle on the API and contribute improvements.

It would be best if we could get these ubercart extensions added into the core node_import, so that others will find and use it. I think in order for that to happen though, cpILL's code will need to properly provide "$values['nid']" in postprocess functions. Right now that'll mess up any other contrib modules which depend on that functionality.